# word wrapping long strings

Tags: java, html, swing, jlist, joptionpane

so i have a solution (a bad one) to split a line within a table's cell - keeping the length of the JOptionPane to what i want it to be and allowing for text to be on multiple lines within a cell. Also if it becomes vertically too long, a scroll bar appears.

currently i have a `loop` which displays 9 words on a line until there are no more words left in the `string`. i'm also using `setText( with 100% width)`

Comment: Classes start with a capital letter. :[

Comment: The preferred method for setting the view port's component is [JViewPort#setView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#setView(java.awt.Component)), but you can shortcut that using JScrollPane#setViewPortView instead

Comment: What happens if you use a different look and feel? What about changing the font size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this. It seemed to work. Trial and error make me come up with this 289px width. You will still have to do something similar to what you are currently doing if you have words that are really long like this: `reallyreallyreallyreallyreallyraellyreallylong`

My solution is below:

```
setText("<html><table style='width:100%'>" + "<tr><td style=\"width:289px;\"><b>" + value + "</b></td></tr>" + "<tr><td style='font-weight:normal;font-size:11;padding-top:-50px;margin-top:-5px;'><i>" + "this is going to have to be pretty long actually" + "</i></td></tr>" + "</table>");
```

Is this something like what you were looking for?

Comment: The `<tbody>` is unnecessary (and seems to be unclosed).  +1 for the simplicity.